# Does the GridSearchCV take in account the execution time of a model or he only takes his accuracy according to the high-parameters?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, gridsearchcv

I'm trying to find the best model for my classification problem. I'm using the GridSearchCV to optimize my models (from sklearn library (DecisionTreeClassifier, RandomForestClassifier,...). I want to know if it takes in account the time execution of the model ?
Ex. I'm optimizing high-params of a DecisionTreeClassifier, he runs in a few seconds, with a specific accuracy. Is the time relevant for the high-params that GridSearch found and retrieves me ?

I Hope it's clear enough !
Thank's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not taken into account, however you can return that information and use it to find the best model with the dictionary that is returned `cv_results_`. Regarding [best_estimator_](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html):

> best_estimator_:
>   Estimator that was chosen by the search, i.e. estimator which gave highest score (or smallest loss if specified) on the left out data. Not available if refit=False.